# What is the diffrence of port 1099 and others when bind RMI in Geronimo?

Tags: port, bind, rmi, geronimo

I am trying starting RMI server in Geronimo.
When I bind a RMI object to default 1099 port, without security/policy options,
there will be security errors, or AccessControl error errors if use 
 System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
without security policy, there will be access control exception.
But when I bind it to other port, such as 9090,
it will succeed without security/policy.

Can someone teach me what's the diffrence of the ports please?

Comment: This is all very confused. If you don't use a security manager you don't get any errors. If you use a security manager but don't use a policy file that grants the required permissions, you get security exceptions. If you use a security manager and a policy file with all required permissions, it works. I can't tell what category your final sentence comes into. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don's know what security config the Geronimo is using as default, and I didn't changed any config, the only diffrent is use port 1099 or 9090.